# Perl: creating zombies through open() without close()

Tags: perl, file-io, filehandle, zombie-process

Here is the problem:
I've a daemon which get requests from a client, executes a function (from some module) due to the request and returns an answer to the client. 
After the fork() I close STDIN,STDOUT and STDERR.
One function is to check dmesg. For this I get the dmesg output through
open(DMESG, "/bin/dmesg |"). I don't close this fh after reading from it, because I thought that it would close automatically after the function finished.
But this doesn't happen and I get a zombie for each call of dmesg.

On [How can I reinitialize Perl's STDIN/STDOUT/STDERR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348639/how-can-I-reinitialize-perls-stdin-stdout-stderr) I found "The problem with closing STDOUT instead of reopening is that if you open other files, they might get fd 0,1 or 2 - preventing you from reopening STDOUT in the future." by jmanning2k
And I think that it has something to do with it but I don't really get it. I hope that someone can explain it to me.

I know that I can avoid the the problem e.g. by calling dmesg via qx(); or simply closing the fh but I want to understand where the zombies are coming from.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The form

```
open DMESG, "/bin/dmesg|";
```

Opens the pipe and assigns it to the **dynamically scoped** variable `DMESG`.  Dynamically scoped variables actually live "forever" in Perl, being saved as necessary whenever a `local` is seen.

If you instead use the form

```
open my $dmesg, "/bin/dmesg|";
```

The **lexical** filehandle variable `$dmesg` will be closed on scope exit, assuming there's no other reason to keep it alive (i.e. it's not passed back or otherwise stored in a global variable).

Answer (score 6):

> `open(DMESG, "/bin/dmesg |")`
>   I don't close this fh after reading from it, because i thought that it would close automatically after the function finished.

For this to work, the handle must be lexical, so it can fall properly out of scope.

```
open my $dmesg, …
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem has to do with the way Perl is implemented.  Here's a piece of code from the function `Perl_do_openn` in file `doio.c`:

```c
fd = PerlIO_fileno(IoIFP(io));
if (IoTYPE(io) == IoTYPE_STD) {
    /* This is a clone of one of STD* handles */
    result = 0;
}
else if (fd >= 0 && fd <= PL_maxsysfd) {
    /* This is one of the original STD* handles */
    saveifp  = IoIFP(io);
    saveofp  = IoOFP(io);
    savetype = IoTYPE(io);
    savefd   = fd;
    result   = 0;
}
```

If you open an existing  filehandle, the filehandle will be closed and reopened by `open()`.  This doesn't happen with `STD*` handles, as you can see from the code above.  So Perl takes the next free handle for opening and the older one remains open.