# Perl's odd behavior when reassigning a filehandle variable from STDOUT to a file without undef()

Tags: perl, warnings, stdout, filehandle

When executing the following simplified code:

```
use strict;                                          # [01]
use warnings FATAL => 'unopened';                    # [02]
                                                     # [03]
my ($inHandle, $outHandle) = (\*STDIN, \*STDOUT);    # [04]
print $outHandle "STDOUT  1\n";                      # [05]
                                                     # [06]
# $outHandle re-assigned to outputA.txt ???          # [07]
open($outHandle, ">outputA.txt") or die ("A: $!\n"); # [08]
print $outHandle "FILE A\n";                         # [09]
print             "STDOUT? 2\n";                     # [10]
print STDOUT      "STDOUT  3\n";                     # [11]
close $outHandle;                                    # [12]
                                                     # [13]
# $outHandle is closed                               # [14]
print STDOUT      "STDOUT  4\n";                     # [15]
print             "STDOUT? 5\n";                     # [16]
print $outHandle "FILE CLOSED\n";                    # [17]
                                                     # [18]
# $outHandle re-assigned to outputA.txt ???          # [19]
open($outHandle, ">outputB.txt") or die ("B: $!\n"); # [20]
print $outHandle "FILE B\n";                         # [21]
close $outHandle;                                    # [22]
```

I encounter these following odd behaviors:

1. No warning is raised when printing (line [18]) to a closed (unopened) `$outputHandle` (line [13]), even when `use warnings FATAL => 'unopened';` is used.
2. The output is as follows which is not what I expect.

| STDOUT | outputA.txt | outputB.txt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| STDOUT 1 | FILE A | FILE B |
|  | STDOUT? 2 |  |
|  | STDOUT 3 |  |

This is the output I expect assuming line [17] is commented out and doesn't raise the `warnings FATAL => 'unopened'`

| STDOUT | outputA.txt | outputB.txt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| STDOUT 1 | FILE A | FILE B |
| STDOUT? 2 |  |  |
| STDOUT 3 |  |  |
| STDOUT 4 |  |  |
| STDOUT? 5 |  |  |

As a side note:

1. The original program outputs to STDOUT as default but switches to outputting to a file if there is a parameter passed to the program.
2. I am using "This is perl 5, version 28, subversion 1 (v5.28.1) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread"

Comment: Those line numbers in your question ... I appreciate the idea to provide them right there (for reference?) but it is far more convenient to have code that can readily be copy-pasted, for testing

Comment: I agree with zdim, would love to be able to run the code. (At least they are fixed width, and thus easy to remove in column mode.) Include the line numbers as comments instead in the future (if you wish to include them).

Comment: Nit: They are *handles* (they give you something to hold), not *handlers* (they don't handle anything)

Comment: If you're trying to *temporarily* redirect STDOUT, you'll need to make a backup of the description. Use `local *STDOUT`, or use `>&` to assign dup STDOUT onto another handle and again laterto dup it back onto STDOUT. Better yet, use one of the existing modules out there, like Capture::Tiny

Comment: I have included those line number in a fixed width format for reference. However upon your suggestions (zdim's and ikegami's), I moved them at the end as comments. Also I changed the misleading variable names: from xxxHandler to xxxHandle. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: @MakotoWada Great, thank you for adjusting these things!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the standard output stream<sup>†</sup> gets redirected (reopened) to a file then there is no way to print to the console with it; what was meant to go there is now connected to that file instead. So once that was done then all other prints to `STDOUT`, done one way or another, wind up in the file.

And then that filehandle gets *closed*; after that one cannot print to `STDOUT` anymore.<sup>‡</sup>

So the first table *is* what one should expect.

I do get a warning when printing to an unopened filehandle, so for any and all prints to `STDOUT` after it got closed.    **Edit** ... without `FATAL => 'unopened'` but with normal `warnings` enabled, that is (how I tested for this answer). However, with that warning category alone *there are no* warnings for printing to *closed* filehandles (ones that had been initialized then closed). See [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66380162/4653379).

Some notes:

- A few pages in docs to study: [open](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open), and
  [*Playing with STDIN and STDOUT* (old perlopentut)](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.8/perlopentut#Playing-with-STDIN-and-STDOUT), and
  [*open FILEHANDLE* in perlfunc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc#open-FILEHANDLE%2cEXPR)
- There are ways to manipulate standard streams with control.  One is to "[dup](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open#Duping-filehandles)" (duplicate) it, so after it's been redirected, used, and closed one can restore it. Some examples that come to mind: in posts [on STDOUT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57155796/4653379) and [on redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49979197/4653379). (Note that `$fh = \*STDOUT` creates an alias, so when one of them is changed so is the other.)

  Or, in a separate scope (block will do nicely), do `local *STDOUT;` and after that all mention of `STDOUT` will work with this [local](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub#Temporary-Values-via-local()) copy. Once you leave the scope the global one gets restored.

  Or you can use `select` instead of messing with the `STDOUT` per se.

  Most of these are nicely summarized in a [perl.com article](https://www.perl.com/article/45/2013/10/27/How-to-redirect-and-restore-STDOUT/). For more also see [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6417185/4653379)
- "Three argument" `open` is better: `open my $fh, '<', $file ...` (and check `or die $!`)
- It's called a "[handle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor)," not a "handler"

---

<sup>†</sup>  The [file descriptor 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)), for which Perl provides an opened `STDOUT` filehandle (really `*STDOUT` [glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#Typeglobs-and-Filehandles), but `*` may be omitted when a filehandle is expected, or as a proper reference `\*STDOUT`)

<sup>‡</sup> Even if `STDOUT` hasn't been first redirected, once it is *closed* there is no connection to standard output stream, and there is no simple way to reopen it as it had been.  (There's of course ways to put things out on the terminal.)

In general, closing `STDOUT` isn't a good idea, since many parties expect it to be open.  For one, once fd1 is vacated other things may get it assigned, with bizarre trouble (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9321422/4653379) and [Perl bug #23838](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues/6770)). What if your program forks (in some way), and children processes inherit what they cannot possibly expect? What with the libraries that may get called in the next line? Etc.

There are better ways to manipulate `STDOUT`, mentioned and linked in the text.

If you *need* `STDOUT` to be gone, at least redirect it to `/dev/null` (`nul` on Windows) instead of outright closing it.

Comment: My apology for putting 2 odd behaviors (odd output & no warning) into 1 stackoverflow question ... leading to confusion. Regarding the odd output, I understand now that `open($outHandle, ">outputA.txt")` does not **reassign** `$outHandle` from `STDOUT` to outputA.txt filehandle. Instead it takes the original `STDOUT` assignment and redirects (`>`) to the filehandle. To severe `$outHandle` from `STDOUT` and reuse the variable, it needs to be `undef($outHandle)` before `open($outHandle, ">outputA.txt")` in line [08]. Thank you for making me understand.

Comment: @MakotoWada Thank you for being so careful about common practice in how questions are asked.  Here I think that it is perfectly reasonable that two questions are given, since both stem directly from observed behavior of this test case.  So it is one situation, one code fragment with various behaviors.

Comment: @MakotoWada  The `STDOUT` is a pre-defined filehandle, provided for our convenience, which is associated with the standard output stream (file descriptor 1) and has other useful properties. Once it is "redirected" -- changed so to connect to another resource -- it is very difficult to restore it to its default role.  (One _can_ reopen it to `/dev/tty`, or another suitable device, but that's only a part of its role.)  The lexical variable that is manipulated (`$outHandle`) has `STDOUT` filehandle and what is done to the variable is about the handle.

Comment: @MakotoWada So when we need to manipulate `STDOUT` we first copy it or "dup" it or `local`-ize it, as discussed in docs/posts linked in the text (or use `select`).  _Then_ we can later restore it in its full role.  If it gets attached to something else, or closed, before it is (properly) "backed up" in some way, then for all practical purposes it is lost as a connection to the standard output stream.  All of this holds if it is done a to a lexical variable to which `*STDOUT` glob is assigned; then that variable represents it, stands for it.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful comments, regarding the following I still get no error or a warning.

> I do get a warning when printing to an unopened filehandle, so for any and all prints to STDOUT after you've closed it.

Maybe it has to do with my Perl version (perl 5, version 28, subversion 1 (v5.28.1) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread). May I ask what version of Perl you are using? Also I have created a separate code and stackoverflow entry in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66380162/no-error-or-warning-for-trying-to-print-to-an-already-closed-filehandle)

Comment: @MakotoWada Thank you very much for mentioning this again! I tested this without using `FATAL`, thinking that it wouldn't matter -- but it does! I posted an answer to the new question with what I found about it.  So it was completely right to ask separately, thank you!  (I also edited this answer accordingly)

Answer (score 0):

Calling `undef($outHandle)` just before line [08] will do the job for output.
However `undef($outHandle)` does not solve the no warning being raised when printing to a closed (unopened) filehandle at line [18].

Comment: You can also call line [08] with `my` like so: `open(my $outHandle, ">outputA.txt") or die ("A: $!\n");`

Comment: The issue regarding no warning is mentioned and resolved here: [No error or warning for trying to print to an already closed filehandle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66380162/no-error-or-warning-for-trying-to-print-to-an-already-closed-filehandle)