# How to disable the warning in module Image::EXIF

Tags: perl, exif

Good day!
When you run this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Image::EXIF;
my $exif = new Image::EXIF($ARGV[0] || 'image3.jpg');
```

displayed a warning (a warning is not at all the pictures.):

(null): unknown TIFF field type; discarding (Unknown)

Is it possible to suppress this warning?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code of that module, it has a XS native part, and the c function that is called looks like this (at file "exifutil.c"):

```
void exifwarn2(const char *msg1, const char *msg2)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s (%s)\n", progname, msg1, msg2);
}
```

As you can see, it prints to STDERR, so you can handle STDERR properly before the call to the  Image::EXIF constructor. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348639/how-can-i-reinitialize-perls-stdin-stdout-stderr) may helps you.