# Perl open external command with custom filehandles

Tags: perl, ipc

Is there a perl function, either built in, or in a library that is like the following:

```
run(IN_FILEHANDLE, OUT_FILEHANDLE, ERR_FILEHANDLE, $cmd);
```

Which gets the external command to read from IN_FILEHANDLE, write to OUT_FILEHANLE, with stderr going to ERR_FILEHANDLE.

e.g.

```
run(STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR, $cmd);
```

Will be similar to:

```
system($cmd);
```

And:

```
run(IN, OUT, ERR, $cmd);
```

Will be a bit like a non-existant version of:

```
open(IN, OUT, ERR, "|$cmd|");
```

I find `open($fh, "|$cmd");`, and `open($fh, "$cmd|");` easy to use, I just read/write from the filehandle. I just want one that works both ways.

Bonus points if one can also optionally read/write to a scalar instead.

I've been mucking around with [`open3`](http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Open3.html) and [`IPC::Run`](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/IPC-Run-0.92/) but I can't seem to get them to work. Working example (perhaps with say `grep`) would be appreciated.

**Edit: In response to comment, my current code:**

```
open3($stdin_fh, $stdout_fh, $stderr_fh, $refresh_exec); #1
print "Opened"; #2
print $stdin_fh "Input to command\n"; #3
```

seems to hang before reaching line #2

and using `IPC::Run`:

```
start \@cmd_arr, $stdin_fh, $stdout_fh, $stderr_fh;
print "Opened"; #2
print $stdin_fh "Input to command\n"; #3
```

Runs the command but writes gives the error: `Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference`.

I know my code is incomplete, but I don't want to paste 400 lines of code, and if I could successfully cut it down and isolate the problem I wouldn't need to ask the question.

I'm even unsure whether `open3` or `IPC::Run` do what I want, so I'm just looking for a working solution I can build on.

Comment: Why don't you show the code you're using with `run3` and explain exactly what's not working?

Comment: Are you putting `\n` at the end of `Input to command`?

Comment: Yes. Edited. There were actually many lines of input in my code. Like I said, a working example would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would:

1. Redirect STD* to the desired FH's.
2. Execute `system($cmd);`
3. Restore STD* to their original state.

Have a look at *Hari's* example for detailed approach:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1720592/1485996

You may also use `local` to avoid restoring STD.

Comment: Can you show an example of how this allows me to `print` directly to `$cmd`s input like when using `open($fh, "|$cmd")`?